# Hono adapters cannot connect to enmasse

Tags: openshift, okd, eclipse-hono

I'm currently installing hono together with enmasse on top of openshift/okd. Everything goes fine except for the connection between the adapters and enmasse. When I deploy the amqp adapter for example (happens with http and mqtt adapter as well), I'm getting following logging from the hono adapter:

```
12:25:45.404 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - starting attempt [#5] to connect to server [messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc:5672]
12:25:45.404 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc:5672]
12:25:47.720 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - can't connect to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc:5672]: connection timed out: messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc.cluster.local/172.30.83.158:5672
12:25:47.720 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - connection attempt failed
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc.cluster.local/172.30.83.158:5672
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:125)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12:25:47.720 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - can't connect to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc:5672]: connection timed out: messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc.cluster.local/172.30.83.158:5672
12:25:47.720 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - connection attempt failed
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: messaging-hono-default.enmasse-infra.svc.cluster.local/172.30.83.158:5672
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:125)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Enmasse logs following:

```
2019-01-07 12:36:24.962160 +0000 SERVER (info) [160]: Accepted connection to 0.0.0.0:5672 from 10.128.0.1:44664
2019-01-07 12:36:24.962258 +0000 SERVER (info) [160]: Connection from 10.128.0.1:44664 (to 0.0.0.0:5672) failed: amqp:connection:framing-error No valid protocol header found
```

Additional info:

- Hono version: 0.8.x
- Enmasse version: 0.24.1

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks!
PS: if somebody with enough reputation could add a newly "enmasse" tag, would be nice.

Comment: have you been following the instructions on the Hono website for deploying to OpenShift/enMasse? Does it work with enMasse 0.20.0 as indicated there?

Comment: I've followed the instructions on https://www.eclipse.org/hono/deployment/openshift_s2i/.
I've been testing with enmasse 0.24.0 (as indicated on the website). Can you provide the link where it is mentioned to use 0.20.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem.
First of all: the framing errors are not incoming connections from hono. I already see this logging when enmasse is installed without installing hono. I don't know where they are coming from. If somebody has an idea, please tell me.
As for the real problem: it seems I needed to allow communication between the two projects (enmasse-infra and hono). This is documented on the [Openshift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html).
**TLDR**

- Used solution: `oc adm pod-network make-projects-global enmasse-infra`. I used this because the enmasse framework needs to be reachable by all projects (including hono but also ditto and our custom backend application).
- Should also work (not tested): `oc adm pod-network join-projects --to=enmasse-infra hono`